# How to remove redundant element content in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, attributes

I am working on a html code below which is coming on inspect. In the code below for the `class="schedule-wrapper"` there is an attribute 
`data-timezone` which has the value `"et"`. The `data-timezone` attribute value changes on button click as shown in the **screenshot below**.  On button click (`PT`, `MT`, `CT`, `ET`, `AT`, `NT`), page refresh doesn't happen.

[image]

```
<div class="schedule-wrapper" id="js-schedule" data-timezone="et">         /* The value of data-timezone attribute changes on button click from the Screenshot below */ 

   <!-- List of button start -->
   <div class="schedule-action-bar">
      <div class="schedule-timezone-filter">
         Select your timezone:            
         <ul id="js-timezone-picker">
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-ct" class="" data-timezone="ct">CT</button>
            </li>
            <li>
               <button id="js-time-et" class="" data-timezone="et">ET</button>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- List of button end -->

    <!-- .schedule-show -->
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
              <time datetime="02:45 24-07-2019" data-timezone="ct">July 24  02:45</time>
               <time datetime="03:45 24-07-2019" data-timezone="et">July 24  03:45</time>           /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .schedule-show -->
    <div class="schedule-show">
        <div class="schedule-show-time">
              <time datetime="04:00 24-07-2019" data-timezone="ct">July 24  04:00</time>
              <time datetime="05:00 24-07-2019" data-timezone="et">July 24  05:00</time>            /* When timezone is eastern standard time */
        </div>
    </div>
   <!-- .schedule-show -->

</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what Javascript code I need to add  so that we can  hide (or ghost out / make less visually prominent) the date when the value is the same as previous row meaning 
not displaying a day on a row where the date is the same as the previous row so that there are visual breaks by date.

In short, as mentioned in the screen-shot above I don't want that date marked with a circle.

Comment: So you want to keep the time no matter what, but remove dates that are the same as their predecessors?

Comment: Yes, you got it. :)

Comment: Start reducing your problem so you can tackle it yourself: you've described two rows of HTML in which some parts are the same and some aren't, so create that HTML, by hand: make an html document with _only_ that code in it, and a script tag. In that vastly simpler scenario, how might you tackle this? What can you query the document for to find "those date/time cells", for example? And how can you iterate through them in a way that you're looking at two cells at a time? Also, what _generates_ this HTML? Perhaps you can in fact change the _generator_ so you don't even need client-side fixing.

Comment: More information. The value `(et, ct)` of `data-timezone` attribute in the 1st line changes on button click without refreshing the page as present in the screenshot above.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What generates this html ? Its a php that generating this html. I don't think so we should do from the server side as on button click, page refresh doesn't happen.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In the screenshot there are 6 buttons, on clicking that button page refresh doesn't happen.

Comment: Please remember that if you have new information, based on questions in comments, that information [belongs in the post](/help/how-to-ask). If there is a PHP script that's generating the HTML, then I would absolutely make PHP responsible for pruning those fields as necessary: I assume it's working on standard sql rows, generating HTML for each row blindly: make it not be blind. Make it remember the last row, and have it generate the text content for that `<time>` element with repeat dates removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I made a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/scf19vt4/)

```
// we have to iterate backwards... actually maybe we don't..
$($('.schedule-show').get().reverse()).each(function(i, div){
  let time = $(div).find('[data-timezone="et"]')
  let nextTime = $(div).find('+ .schedule-show [data-timezone="et"]')
  if(nextTime[0]){
    // check if the dates match
    if(nextTime.text().match(/\w+ \d+/)[0] === time.text().match(/\w+ \d+/)[0]){
      // "white out" the dates that match
      nextTime.html(nextTime.text().replace(/(\w+ \d+)/, "<font color=\"white\">$1</font>"))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have one issue coming up. I have both English and French Months. English months are working perfectly fine. Thanks for that. 

 In regards to French months, I believe it’s not reading French characters or anything after that. Check this https://postimg.cc/jL2YFPKR The characters inside the circle should be hidden.

Comment: I have made the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ec8m2p6z/7/). I am wondering if we can hide ût.

Comment: I forked it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g3L9pswj/) - just change \w to [\wû] and include whatever other accented chars required